# Problems building a SquareMatrix template class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, nested

I am trying to build a `SquareMatrix` template class by using a constructor that accepts 4 parameters as the 4 submatrices `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` occupying the four quadrants (`a` = northwest, `b` = northeast, `c` = southwest, `d` = southeast) of the matrix. Shown below:

```
    template<class T> class SquareMatrix {
    public:
        SquareMatrix(){}
        SquareMatrix(const T first, const T second, const T third, const T fourth) {
            a = first;
            b = second;
            c = third;
            d = fourth;
        }
        SquareMatrix<T>(const SquareMatrix<T>& rhs) { // copy constructor
            a = rhs.getA();
            b = rhs.getB();
            c = rhs.getC();
            d = rhs.getD();
        }
        SquareMatrix& operator=(const SquareMatrix rhs) {  // assignment operator
            if (&rhs != this) {
                SquareMatrix(rhs);
            }

            return *this;
        }
        ~SquareMatrix() {}  // destructor

        // getters and setters
        T getA() const {return a;}
        T getB() const {return b;}
        T getC() const {return c;}
        T getD() const {return d;}
        void setA(const T& input) {a = input;}
        void setB(const T& input) {b = input;}
        void setC(const T& input) {c = input;}
        void setD(const T& input) {d = input;}

    private:   
        // 4 quadrants
        // [a, b;
        //  c, d]
        T a, b, c, d;
    };

    template<class T> SquareMatrix<T> operator+(const SquareMatrix<T> lhs, 
                      const SquareMatrix<T>& rhs) {
        SquareMatrix<T> ret(lhs);
        ret.setA( ret.getA() + rhs.getA() );
        ret.setB( ret.getB() + rhs.getB() );
        ret.setC( ret.getC() + rhs.getC() );
        ret.setD( ret.getD() + rhs.getD() );

        return ret;
    };
    template<class T> SquareMatrix<T> operator-(const SquareMatrix<T> lhs,
                      const SquareMatrix<T>& rhs) {
        SquareMatrix<T> ret(lhs);
        ret.setA( ret.getA() - rhs.getA() );
        ret.setB( ret.getB() - rhs.getB() );
        ret.setC( ret.getC() - rhs.getC() );
        ret.setD( ret.getD() - rhs.getD() );

        return ret;
    };
    // this is the implementation of Strassen's algorithm
    template<class T> SquareMatrix<T> operator*(const SquareMatrix<T>& lhs, 
                      const SquareMatrix<T>& rhs) {
        T product_1 = lhs.getA() * ( rhs.getB() - rhs.getD() );
        T product_2 = ( lhs.getA() + lhs.getB() ) * rhs.getD();
        T product_3 = ( lhs.getC() + lhs.getD() ) * rhs.getA();
        T product_4 = lhs.getD() * ( rhs.getC() - rhs.getA() );
        T product_5 = ( lhs.getA() + lhs.getD() ) * ( rhs.getA() + rhs.getD() );
        T product_6 = ( lhs.getB() - lhs.getD() ) * ( rhs.getC() + rhs.getD() );
        T product_7 = ( lhs.getA() - lhs.getC() ) * ( rhs.getA() + rhs.getB() );
        SquareMatrix<T> ret;
        ret.setA(product_5 + product_4 - product_2 + product_6);
        ret.setB(product_1 + product_2);
        ret.setC(product_3 + product_4);
        ret.setD(product_1 + product_5 - product_3 - product_7);

        return ret;
    };
```

Now, I am trying to create a nested 4x4 matrix, by doing:

```
    int main() {
        cout << "Example: a 4x4 matrix: " << endl;
        // 4 single quadrants 
        SquareMatrix<int> M_1A(1, 2, 3, 4);
        SquareMatrix<int> M_1B(5, 6, 7, 8);
        SquareMatrix<int> M_1C(9, 10, 11, 12);
        SquareMatrix<int> M_1D(13, 14, 15, 16);
        // 4x4 matrix M_1
        SquareMatrix< SquareMatrix<int> > M_1(M_1A, M_1B, M_1C, M_1D);
        // test
        cout << "test: " << endl;
        cout << M_1.getA().getA() << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

The intended matrix output should be `M_1 = [1,2,5,6; 3,4,7,8; 9,10,13,14; 11,12,15,16]`.
I use the `M_1.getA().getA()` command to first access `M_1A` and then access `1` nested inside it, but instead the output display a big number that constantly changes, perhaps an address? (last time I tried it yielded 6684672).
Is there a way to implement a matrix class in this manner?

(EDIT: now included assignment operator and destructor, likely sources of the bug)

Comment: FYI, you don't need a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: I omitted destructor and assignment operator from the code snippet above.

Comment: What is there to copy or assign?  If `T` is safely copyable by itself, there is no need for those functions (or a destructor).  All you're doing is risking introducing bugs by stepping in the way of the compiler.  Second, you should post *all* of your code.  If the reason for the bugs is a buggy user-defined assignment operator, then we will never see the error.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdbd433113922647)

Comment: You're a beast, now it passes this test. I thought I was safe in always including the rule of three for my custom classes. Casts a big shadow over my c++ convictions. Here after all I am dealing with a `T = SquareMatrix<int>` which is not a built-in type, hence copy and assignment should not come already synthetised...

Comment: That's ok.  All you need to be concerned with are the members of your class.  If all the members themselves can be copied, then there is no need to provide a user-defined versions of these functions.  Since your members contain `int`, then you're ok.  Even if the user provided a type that cannot be copied, that's their problem, not `SquareMatrix`s problem.  The prerequisite would be that `T` is copyable and assignable.

Comment: So if I want, for instance, a copy of an 8x8 matrix `M_2(M_1)` where `M_1` would then be of type `SquareMatrix<SquareMatrix<SquareMatrix<int> > >`, I don't need a `copy` constructor because the compiler will automagically drill down three levels of nesting to `int`?

Comment: The simple answer is "yes", everything will work without writing copy constructor, assignment operator.  Look at your declaration -- it is really nothing more than a `SquareMatrix<T>`, where `T` is of some type.   Does it matter what `T` is, as long as `T` is copyable?  If `SquareMatrix<int>` is the base case, and it is copyable, then `SquareMatrix<SquareMatrix<int>>` is also copyable, etc.

Comment: Mmmh to your last question I would answer that for `SquareMatrix<SquareMatrix<SquareMatrix<int> > >` the compiler would want to call the copy constructor of `SquareMatrix<T>`. Assuming that it doesn't find one, it would try to synthetise it from  `T = SquareMatrix<SquareMatrix<int> >` and so on drilling down until it finds the built-in `int` type.

Comment: Your assignment operator isn't doing any assignment.

Comment: The bug lies in the assignment `operator=`, that should copy `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` directly from `rhs` instead of trying to call the copy constructor in a way that is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested, it is the assignment operator that is faulty.

```
SquareMatrix& operator=(const SquareMatrix rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
         SquareMatrix(rhs); // <-- This creates a temporary that 
                            // dies off after that line is executed
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The assignment operator doesn't do any assignment.  Instead a temporary `SquareMatrix` is made.

To fix this problem, either

1) Not supply any assignment operator, copy constructor, or destructor, since the type `T` should be safely copyable.

2) Fix the assignment operator so that it works correctly:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
SquareMatrix& operator=(const SquareMatrix rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
         SquareMatrix t(rhs); 
         std::swap(t.a, a); 
         std::swap(t.b, b); 
         std::swap(t.c, c); 
         std::swap(t.d, d); 
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The assignment now works.  However I suggest not writing code that need not be written, and your buggy implementation is the case in point.

In your case, if you let the compiler generate the assignment operator and/or rely on `T` in the template to have correct copy semantics, your class would have worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's comments are right on the mark.  Although your SquareMatrix is not built-in, it is declared to be consisting of 4 elements of type T.  The default copy c'tor for your class will be using the assignment operator or assignment c'tor of the actual type that T is representing in your usage.

I have some suggestions to improve the code:

1. If T is of a type that has a memory footprint that is bigger than a pointer/int: it is more efficient to let your c'tor receive the elements bij const reference like so:

```cpp
    SquareMatrix( const T& _a, const T& _b, const T& _c, const T& _d)
```

2. Use copy constructors as much as possible: that way the four elements don't get initialized first and then assigned later.  Instead, they get initialized with the correct values at once.

```cpp
     SquareMatrix( const T& _a, const T& _b, const T& _c, const T& _d)
     : a( _a), b( _b), c( _c), d( _d)
     { /* empty body */ }
```

3. Choose your names wisely to simplify things.  Don't introduce extra mappings in name schemes when you don't have to;  it just creates opportunities to slip.  I already applied that in point 1 above :-).
4. Don't 'program by wishful thinking': writing in comments or type/variable names that something is supposed to be something will not make it that. In your case: your class IS NOT a square matrix, nor even a matrix.  To the compiler it is a data type consisting of four elements, named a, b, c and d, respectively, of a type T to be defined at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Sure passing by reference is to be preferred in this case. Also will substitute `first` etc. with `_a`, makes sense.
I have added declaration for three operators, `+`, `-`, `*`. `SquareMatrix` is a bit of a toy class, hope now it looks more complete. In fact I have written it to check the performance of the Strassen algorithm for matrix multiplication